# Transitivity of a Boolean Matrix?

Tags: matrices

I'm wondering if there's an easy way of visually telling if a boolean matrix has transitivity?

The question in particular is:

```
A relation p on the set X = {a,b,c,d} is represented by the following Boolean matrix.
1  0  1  1
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  1
1  0  1  1

Which of the properties below does p have?
Symmetric
Reflexive
Transitive
Equivalence relation
```

Is there an easy way of telling if it's transitive? My method would be to write out all ordered pairs and check manually.
Thanks!

Comment: You could find the transitive closure using Warshall's algorithm, but in general that can be tedious to calculate by hand.